# Angularjs - I get data.data, but can't assign scope variable to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, http

I'm working on an AngularJS-based site that gets questions and multiple choice answers from an Amazon Web Services table in order to dynamically build a prelab questions page. The http get works fine - when I place breakpoints and evaluate the value of *data.data*, which gives all the data I'm looking for.

However, upon assigning that to *$scope.allQuestions*, said variable evaluates to *undefined* in the console. The same happens for *$scope.allAnswers*. On a different page, I use the same code to get thumbnails/simulation URLs without a problem.

The *$location* stuff is working fine, and I inject *$filter* for filtering in an *ng-repeat* thing later.

I use the API Gateway on AWS to call this. I have CORS enabled, and I use the same settings for the two functions here that I use in the other function that works.

Code is below. Thanks in advance!

```js
app.service('preLabService', function($http) {
  this.getQuestions = function() {
    return $http.get('api-gateway-url');
  };
  this.getAnswers = function() {
    return $http.get('api-gateway-url');
  };
});

app.controller('PreLabQuestionsCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$filter', 'preLabService', function($scope, $location, $filter, preLabService) {
  init();

  function init() {
    preLabService.getQuestions().then(function(data) {
      $scope.allQuestions = data.data;
    });
    preLabService.getAnswers().then(function(data) {
      $scope.allAnswers = data.data;
    });
    $scope.simURL = $location.search().simURL;
    $scope.simID = $location.search().SimID;
  }
}]);
```

In the code I actually run in my browser, I do replace *'api-gateway-url' with their respective urls - I just didn't want to give out the API url here.

Comment: Try calling `$scope.$apply();` after you assign `data.data` to `$scope.allQuestions`.

Comment: are $scope.simURL & $scope.simID used for make the requests? try to reorder them

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu *$scope.$apply();* results in the error $rootScope.inprog.

Comment: @IgorL No, $scope.simURL is used to filter it dynamically - this is done for cost effectiveness, it actually costs slightly less to just get all the values from the DynamoDB table rather than run a dynamic query on it. $scope.simURL is used to determine where a button on the page should go.

Comment: also try to add catch to the getters preLabService.getQuestions().then(function(data) {
      $scope.allQuestions = data.data;
    }).catch(...);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I discovered that I'm an idiot.

I was storing the data.data in $scope.allAnswers, but in the ng-repeat attribute, I was attempting to repeat over $scope.answers. I've fixed it and it works fine.

Ended up not needing to use apply or set a const vm value - I just made a stupid mistake.

Thanks for your answers regardless!

Answer (score 0):

You really need to add thi to a $scope variable?

Can you try:

```
const vm = this
```

and then assign the data value to vm.allQuestions and vm.allAnswers?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you could call `$scope.$apply()` after assigning `data.data` to the `$scope.$allQuestions` variabile.

The recommended though way is to wrap the callback in a `$scope.$apply()` to instruct Angular to run another digest cycle. This can be done like so, within your callback function:

```
preLabService.getQuestions().then(function(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.allQuestions = data.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: as far as I know if you use $http service of angular you not need it, after all 'then' callbacks of $http, angular run $apply implicitly.